# Unable to increase Socket buffer size using socket_recv

Tags: php, websocket

I have successfully created a web-socket connection and able to send and receive data properly. However, I am unable to increase socket receive buffer size.

By using the below code, I can restrict receiving bytes to 1000 to less.

```
$bytes = socket_recv($socket,$buffer,2048,0);
```

However, when I tried to increase it length to 65536 Bytes, it is not increased.
I am using below mentioned credentials to create the web-socket connection.

```
set_time_limit ( 0 ) ;
ob_implicit_flush ( ) ;
$master=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("socket_create() failed");
socket_set_option($master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) or die("socket_option() failed");
socket_bind($master, $address, $port) or die("socket_bind() failed");
socket_listen($master,20) or die("socket_listen() failed");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MSG_WAITALL` option in the `flags` argument to tell it not to return until `len` bytes have been received.

Comment: sir, i tried it but by using it my program get stuck and handshake process is not completing ..

Comment: You can't do a handshake with this, if the client isn't going to send all 64KB at once. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Actually i want to learn more about about HTML5 websocket, currently i am not using it in my applications but in future i will try this.... rite now i am trying to create a small web application/page where i can send all my HTML content using WS protocol, so by experimenting in it i am able to send large HTML content to web browser but not able to receive at server side and i think if works my application will be very fast and real time.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to increase the buffer to 64KByte? Im sure in most cases this makes not much sense. The maximum size of the socket buffers surely depends also on the underlying implementation. Maybe there is an internal maximum size you can not exceed.
If you want to receive bigger data/messages you should use the `socket_recv` function call multiple times.

By the way, if you are using PHP you should take a look for some powerful Framework. I think its not a good idea to try to use RAW sockets.

Comment: sir, i tried to retrieve data in loop but when i do this my data get corrupted. it return me some byte and rest of all get blank.

Comment: Remember that `socket_recv` returns the number of bytes read. You must not try to access parts of the buffer after that, they aren't valid.